# How to trim the last one or last two characters of a string

Tags: javascript

I have an object with a bunch of strings:

```
[
    {
        date: "03/12/2014",
        name: "mr blue",
        title: "math teacher -"
    },
    {
        date: "04/02/2015",
        name: "mrs yellow",
        title: "chemistry teacher"
    },
    {
        date: "11/04/2014",
        name: "mrs green",
        title: "chemistry teacher - "
    },
]
```

How can i strip the -  from the title field if that string contains a -.

I know a can perform a slice/subtring:

```
var myvalue = myobject.title.substring(0, myobject.title.length-1);
```

However this will apply for all cases, and not just the ones that contain the -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var myvalue = myobject.title.replace(/\s*-\s*$/,'');
```

Bonus: with this regular expression only a dash at the end will be removed (along with the spaces around).

Comment: Thanks - are there any browser limitations of .replace?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var title = 'math teacher -';
title = title.replace('-', '').trim();
document.write(title);
```

**Update**

Above will fail if `title` has dashes in the middle. Therefore, using `lastIndexOf` you can do

```
title = title.substring(0,oldString.lastIndexOf("-")).trim;
```